# What is the minimum thickness a new top layer of concrete should be when poured over an existing concrete walkway?

Tags: repair, concrete, sidewalk

Parts of a concrete walkway leading up to the front of the house have sunk down over the years. We want to add a layer of new concrete over the old concrete to raise it and make it more even.  What is the minimum thickness we can pour to not compromise the strength?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to put 3" down you would be better served to do a new walkway. Have you looked into "slabjacking" or "mudjacking" to raise your old slabs. Might be cheaper if the surface of your old slabs is still in good shape.

Comment: We are aware of this process, but in addition to the sinking sidewalk it also looks very worn, so we were wanting to give it a 'facelift'.